# Module not found

Tags: python

Создал простенький проект. Использую виртуальное окружение. Структура проекта следующая:

```
root:
    physical:
        test:
            __init__.py
            test_week.py
        __init__.py
        week_number.py
```

В файле теста я пытаюсь импортировать функцию из модуля week_number.py. Импорт выглядит так:

```
from pytest_mock import mocker

from physical.week_number import get_week_number


def test_get_week_number_1():
    with mocker.patch.object(__builtins__, 'input', lambda: '2021.09.24'):
        assert get_week_number() == 15
```

Но получаю ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'physical'`

Причем строку импорта vsc автоматически находит и прописывает в функции теста, т.е. автоматические средства vsc могут эту зависимость прописать, почему тогда запуск теста не видит модуль?
Попробовал не через тест, а просто создать отдельный файл и там попробовать запустить функцию предварительно ее импортнув. Такая же ошибка.

Comment: а physical.py у вас есть?

Comment: создайте в системном окружении переменную `PYTHONPATH` в которой укажите путь до проекта

Comment: @Сергей нет такого файла нет

Comment: @Namerek да это помогло, спасибо. А можете пояснить почем такое вообще происходит? Это надо всегда делать при любом новом проекте?

Comment: Имеет смысл вынести тесты из пакета physical на уровень выше, тогда при запуске тестов из папки root по идее пакет physycal должен быть доступен для тестов без добавления в PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @Namerek и оформите пожалуйста свой ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его как решение вопроса. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создайте в системном окружении переменную PYTHONPATH в которой укажите путь до проекта