# Python. Импортирование в пакетах

Tags: python, импорт, package

Допустим, у меня есть такой пакет:

> Package:
> | - main.py
> | - __ init__.py
> | - utils.py

Можно ли Создавать **Пакет в пакете**?
Что я имею ввиду:

> Package:
> | - main.py
> | - __ init__.py
> | - utils.py
> | - Package2:
> | - | - event.py
> | - | - Package3:
> | - | - |- command.py

Если да, то как импортировать `utils.py` в `event.py`? Когда пытаюсь сделать такое, выдаёт ошибку:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

Comment: Вы бы код привели, который у вас не работает. Принципиально не вижу проблем импорт делать в импортируемом модуле. Просто практика такая в реальности в средних проектах не очень нужной выглядит.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406314/module-not-found?noredirect=1#comment2499948_1406314

Answer (score 0):

#### Для `event.py`:

```py
import utils
from Package3 import command
```

#### Для `command.py`:

```
import utils
from Package2 import event
```

#### Для `utils.py`:

```
from Package2 import event
from Package2.Package3 import command
```

> Желательно создать переменную окружения `PYTHONPATH` и присвоить ей значение полного пути до корня проекта