# Module not found. Again?

Tags: python

Всем привет. У меня повторилась проблема описанная тут, только уже не в тестах. [Module not found](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406314/module-not-found)

Ситуация следующая есть папка D:\repositories\ED.
Переменная PYTHONPATH имеет значение D:\repositories\ED.
В ней есть папка elements  в которой три файла: element.py, node.py и **init**.py
Создано виртуальное окружение в папке .venv
В итоге структура такая:\

```
ED:
    .venv
    elements:
        __init__.py
        element.py
        node.py
```

В файле elements.py определен класс Element
В файле node.py определен класс Node, который наследуется от класса Element. При попытке импорта класса Element в node.py возникает ошибка module not found.

```
from elements.element import Element


class Node(Element):

    def __init__(
        self,
        is_base: bool = False,
        elements: Union[list, tuple, tensor] = None
    ) -> None:
        self.is_base = is_base
        self.elements = elements
```

Т.е. если попытаться создать объект класса Node, вот таким образом:

```
from elements.element import Element


class Node(Element):

    def __init__(
        self,
        is_base: bool = False,
        elements: Union[list, tuple, tensor] = None
    ) -> None:
        self.is_base = is_base
        self.elements = elements


node = Node(name='node', u_nom=220.0)
```

то получаем ошибку

```
(.venv) PS D:\repositories\ED> & d:/repositories/ED/.venv/Scripts/python.exe d:/repositories/ED/elements/node.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\repositories\ED\elements\node.py", line 7, in <module>
    from elements.element import Element
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'elements'
```

Складывается ощущение, что у меня есть какое то фундаментальное не понимание сути происходящего. Отчего возникает подобная ошибка? Отдельное спасибо если кинете ссылку на место где можно получить знания на эту тему. Спасибо.

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что, где и как вы запускаете

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Описал подробнее.

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь запускать файл внутри модуля напрямую, то при таком запуске он не считается частью модуля

Comment: @andreymal я не понял Ваш комментарий. Можете объяснить подробнее? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, я кажется разобрался сам. Если мы работаем в разных модулях, но внутри одного пакета (т.е. внутри папки с **init**.py файлом) elements, то доступ к отдельным модулям пакета должен происходить напрямую без указания самого пакета. Т.е. импортируем класс из другого модуля так:

```
from module import class
```

Если же мы работаем внутри другой папки, то доступ к модулям пакета elements уже происходит так:

```
from package.module import class
```